# Working out standard units

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis

I have the question " Newton's Gravitational Law is given as. $F =  G (mM/r)$,
Where $m$ and $M$ are masses, $r$ is the distance between the masses and $F$ is the attraction force, and $G$ is a constant.

Derive the dimension of $G$ and work out the standard units for $G$?"

So I have rearranged the equation to make $G$ the subject so I get $G = F (mM/r)$.

I then put in the units where $F = [\text{kg}\cdot\text{m}\cdot\text{s}^{-2}]$, $m$ and $M = [\text{kg}]$ and $r = [\text{m}]$.

The final answer that I get is $G = [\text{kg}^2\cdot\text{m}^2\cdot\text{s}^{-2}]$ is This correct ? And if not could you explain where I went wrong?

Comment: Using $m$ for both meters and mass in bound to be confusing.  Why not use $m_1,m_2$ for your two masses just to avoid the problem?

Comment: But Newton's Gravitational Law is _not_ given by $F=G(mM/r)$...

Comment: It should be $r^2$ not $r$

Comment: As @CaveJohnson says, it should have a $r^2$ instead of just a $r$ - what you have written is a potential.

Comment: Also your rearrangment is not correct, it should be $G=F(r^2/mM)$

Comment: So would the final answer for g be [kg^3m^3s^-2]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the physics law (p.s. you are missing an $r$!)

$$F = G \frac{mM}{r^2}$$

You get

$$G = \frac{F r^2}{mM}$$

Hence the dimensions are well given:

$$[G] = \frac{[N]\cdot [m]^2}{[kg]^2}$$

Now, the Newton is not an elementary unit, and you can obtain it by the simplest force:

$$F = ma$$

Hence

$$[F] = \text{kg}\cdot \text{m}/\text{s}^2$$

SUbstituting above:

$$[G] = \frac{[kg]\cdot [m]}{[s]^2}\cdot \frac{[m]^2}{[kg]^2}$$

Hence

$$[G] = \frac{[m]^3}{[s]^2 \cdot [kg]}$$

Comment: Thank you I understand now, but I still don't get why when the equation is rearranged to make G the subject the r^2 and the mM are flipped ?

Comment: @Dan If $a=\frac{bc}{d}$ then $b=\frac{ad}{c}$, since you multiply by $d$ and divide by $c$ in order to isolate $b$.

Comment: But would the standard unit for g not be [kg^3m^3s^-2]?

Comment: No, it's not...just looking at the mass unit you need 1/mass to cancel the mass^2 and wind up with mass^1.

Comment: Ah okay I see. So the standard unit should be [m^3s^2kg] ?

Comment: Just read the answer above...